# Codeigniter 4: Get value from BaseController to custom helper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Seems `get_instance()` is no longer working in Codeigniter 4. But I need to get some value from BaseController to my custom_helper. Here is my code snippet:

**BaseController.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
class BaseController extends Controller
{
 protected $helpers = ['custom'];
 public function initController(...) {
  parent::initController(...);

   $myconfig = config('MyConfig');
   $this->languages = $myconfig->languages;
   $this->selected_lang = $myconfig->site_lang;
   $lang_segment = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1);
   foreach ($this->languages as $lang) {
    if ($lang_segment == $lang->short_form) {
      $this->selected_lang = $lang;
      $this->lang_base_url = base_url() . $lang->short_form . "/";
    }
   }
 }
}
// Here I need to pass ($this->selected_lang) value to my custom_helper.
```

**custom_helper.php**

```
<?php
 if (!function_exists('trans')) {
    function trans($string)
    {
        $language_translations = get_translation_array($this->selected_lang->id);
        // --> Here I want to get ($this->selected_lang->id) value from BaseController.
        
        if (!empty($language_translations[$string])) {
            return $language_translations[$string];
        }
        return "";
    }
 }
 function get_translation_array($land_id)
 {
    .......
 }
```

I'm not sure is it possible or not! I'm newbie in CI4. Please suggest if is there any solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "super object" in CI4 anymore, so `get_instance()` shouldn't work, by design. If a Helper function needs data from the Controller, you should pass it as a function parameter.

Comment: Can you please show me an example code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the BaseController you should do everything within the helper that is

```php
if (!function_exists('trans')) {
    function trans($string)
    {
        $myconfig = config('MyConfig');
        $languages = $myconfig->languages;
        $selected_lang = $myconfig->site_lang;

        $language_translations = get_translation_array($selected_lang->id);
        
        if (!empty($language_translations[$string])) {
            return $language_translations[$string];
        }
        return "";
    }
 }
```

Although I don't know what you are trying to do but I hope this will help you if not call my attentions again

Answer (score 0):

We can access specific piece of data get or post values by retrieving headers into any helper function,

```php
$request = \Config\Services::request();
$data = $request->getVar('foo');
```

You can also refer below documentation. https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#retrieving-headers